# Get Table Row Id ro Row Number with Where condition

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to get the row id or row number for my table.

Here is my code.

```
<?php

include("config.php");

$imgtable_name = "thamana_gallery";
$image_name = "37a4d8b18493d91157b5c5e097e8bd1a6.jpg";

$sql_img = "SELECT 0 INTO @rowId";
mysql_query($sql_img);
$sql_img = "SELECT @rowId := @rowId + 1 as rowid, imgname from $imgtable_name where imgname='$image_name'";
$result_img = mysql_query($sql_img);

$imp_img = mysql_fetch_array( $result_img, MYSQL_ASSOC );

echo $image_name;
echo "<br/>";
echo $imp_img['rowid'];

echo "<br/>";
echo $imp_img['imgname'];

?>
```

Am getting the result as follows :

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
37a4d8b18493d91157b5c5e097e8bd1a6.jpg
1
37a4d8b18493d91157b5c5e097e8bd1a6.jpg
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The image name is in the 6th row the table but am getting the result as 1.

What have I missed?

Comment: The question is not very clear (code formatting could use a bit of improvement).

Comment: `var_dump($imp_img)` or `print_r($imp_img)` to print all output of query, then you can see clearly the issue

Answer (score 0):

Why not just having id-column with primary index and auto-increment? Then, you could just retrieve

```
SELECT id, imgname FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The @row is calculated for each row that is retrieved from the database. If you are retrieving 10 rows you will have it numerated from 1 to 10, if you are retrieving an specific row, as you are limiting by the name, just one row will be returned.

To limit your result to a row with a specific rowId you need to do something like:

```
select * from 
  (
    select @rowId := @rowId + 1 as rowid, imgname from TABLE_NAME order by imgname
  ) a 
where 
  a.imgname=:IMG_NAME
```